# Creating Hexagon from centroids of polygons using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, centroids, hexagonal-grid

How do I create a hexagon from its centroids using ArcMap?

I will show the image below. It is H3 resolution 9.

[image]

This picture illustrate the centroid of the hexagon so I would like to know how to generate it.

Comment: It's too bad that some centroids miss because you could have use a Voronoi algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

You should always check out the code sharing website on the Esri website, there are *many* tools shared by the user community for free. One such tool is [a tool for generating hexagons from points](https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=5f9740037f42431798001026eb311e9a).

Answer (score 0):

First measure minimum distance (L) between pair of points and compute length (X) of edge of hexagon:

```
X=2*L*cos⁡(60)*tan⁡(30)
```

The area of hexagon (A) is:

```
A=6*X^2 √(1.5*0.5*0.5*0.5)
```

Use it to Generate Tessellation (hexagons) with above area, but for much bigger extent than extent of your points:

[image]

Apply spatial adjustment using 3 points sitting at distance L from each other by drawing links from relevant hexagon centroids to above points:

[image]

Adjust hexagons after preview and delete ones that are not intersected by original points:

[image]

As one can see I've missed few points, so make your extent truly big.

Answer (score 0):

If you actually want H3 hexagons, you’ll likely need to preprocess the data before bringing it into ArcMap - I’m not aware of an ArcMap plugin for the H3 library. Preprocessing is relatively straightforward - just map each point to `geoToH3(lat, lng, 9)` and then use `h3ToGeoBoundary(h3Index)` to get the polygon boundary for each cell. You could do this in Python, JavaScript, or whatever language is most convenient for you.